# Get Image from Byte Aarray

Tags: iphone

Hope You all are fine and also in one of your best of moods!!

Hope You all are Enjoying iPhone development.

I herewith one issue that i am not able to solve, may be i don't know the depth concept of iPhone.
So Its my humble requet to you to guide me or suggest or share your ideas.

I do find an issue with getting an image from Bytes array.

I am calling a webservice which returns an image in form of Bytes Array as response.

I have Converted this bytes array in to form of NSData, Now i have NSData, But When i Try to get an image from this NSData, It shows nil.

I Did lots of R&D and Find one suggestion to use base64 encoder, But unfortunately because of not proper guidance I was not able to Implement that.

I was also suggested to use OPenSSL Library for base64 from url http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?BaseSixtyFour

But again i was not able to include #include  #include  these two files. as in Newer Version of SDK 3.X family Apple has depreciated those (as i guess).

So Now i need help from you guys. kindly help me if you have solution or if you know the steps to solve these.

Looking Forwards.

Regards,

Arun Thakkar

Comment: Could you please post the code you have for creating a image from your bytes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using OpenSSL on the iPhone seems like a very heavy-weight solution if all you need is Base64 encoding/decoding. Look at this post for how to use a category for NSData to add base64 encoding/decoding. You want the second section of this blog post as the first deals with OpenSSL :)

[base64-encoding-options-on-mac-and-iphone](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/06/base64-encoding-options-on-mac-and.html)

Comment: Thanks brother!! Its Helpful, So nice of you.