# how to get images from web service xml?

Tags: iphone, xml, xcode, webservice-client

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to read images from xml file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5257057/how-to-read-images-from-xml-file)

how to get images from web service xml?
i want image from xml file formatted as bytes in web services..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Uploading you have to work like this:

```
NSString *encodedString=[self encode:(const uint8_t*)_secretData.bytes length:_secretData.length];
```

encode is a method which is defined in "Base64.h" classes, you can download it anywhere from the internet.

And for retrieving purpose you have to pass the same string in decode method

```
NSData *data=[Base64 decode:your_string];
```

and using data you can perform any operation like

```
UIButton *image = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [image setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageWithData:data] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps

[Get Image from Byte Aarray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910575/get-image-from-byte-aarray)